# How to output certain parts of a text file to a listbox after reading it in - Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, csv, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I currently do Advanced Higher Computing Science and part of the course is a project that we produce on our own. The project I'm producing is a program ran on VB 2010 Express that works as an information system that recommends films based on the user's choice of genre. I'm using 4 buttons to represent the 4 genres and a listbox to represent the recommendations, so a pretty simple user interface.

I can read in the films from a CSV file I've got, the only thing I'm not sure of is how to output the films so that only the films that match the genre chosen will be shown in the listbox rather than all of them at once as that becomes pretty useless.

Below I've got the code I've currently got. So far I only have how I would read in the file for the 4 buttons.

[image: User Interface]

[image: Code I currently have]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as this project is 30% of my final grade.

Thanks :)

Comment: so... can you post some code? so that we can help

Comment: Hey, sorry I've added that now

Comment: FYI VB.NET is not "classic" VB, I removed that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your source file looks like. But you could do the following:

Each line in the csv-file contains the following information:
name_of_film;genre

The file could look like this:
`"Action Movie";"Action"
"Drama Movie";"Drama"
...`

Create two arrays of type string (Name and Genre). Create a loop that reads the file per line and split the string at ';'. Then in your loop, assign the left value to Name[] and the right one to Genre[].

Now, when the button is clicked, use a for-loop to filter the titles by genre. If Genre[i] = 'chosen genre', add Name[i] to listbox.

I won't write the code for you, since you have to learn it yourself :P